# Synergy 1.6.2 on raspberry pi not compatible with v1.4 on Mint Now what?

Tags: linux-mint, raspberry-pi, synergy

Why does every distro have a different version of Synergy? This does not work and needs a fix.
Synergy 1.6.2 on raspberry pi is not compatible with v 1.4 on Mint Now what?

Mint 17.1 synergy wont work with Mint 17.2 synergy or with Windows synergy.
I can't find source, synergy.org down.
All my machines have a different version!

Now what?

Answer (score 0):

You are not stuck with the version of Synergy that your distribution came with, you can update all the installed versions.

The correct website address is synergy-project.org.